# Networkx BFS_Tree from adjacency list

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I am new to networkx, and what I want to do is generate a graph from a .txt adjacency list (successful), the do a bfs_tree on said list. The dfs_tree works, but bfs returns errors saying my source node is not in the graph. I know why, I just need to know how to get it to work.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   
G = nx.read_adjlist("AL.txt")

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()

T = nx.dfs_tree(G)
nx.draw(T, with_labels=True)
plt.show()

T2 = nx.bfs_tree(G, source=1)
nx.draw(T2, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

The data in the .txt file is:

```
1 2 4 5
2 1 4 3
3 2 4 6
4 1 2 3 5 6 7
5 1 4 7 8
6 3 4 7 10
7 4 5 6 10 8
8 5 7 9
9 8 10
10 6 7 9
```

Comment: perhaps you need to share the data to make it reproducible

Comment: Added to the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the text file the default type for the nodes is string. Therefore, you can resolve the issue by adding the node type, see docs of [`read_adjlist`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.adjlist.read_adjlist.html#networkx.readwrite.adjlist.read_adjlist):

```
G = nx.read_adjlist("AL.txt", nodetype=int)
```

or by building the `bfs_tree` from `"1"`:

```
T2 = nx.bfs_tree(G, source="1")
```

Comment: You're welcome, take a look at the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;)